# Simplifying Specific Multiple Regular Expressions and String method

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I am trying to convert a string to Spinal Tap case. (Spinal case is all-lowercase-words-joined-by-dashes). Challenge at [freeCodeCamp](https://www.freecodecamp.org/challenges/spinal-tap-case). Although **my code is working**, I would like to know how to simplify it i.e., combine the two regular expressions into one and combine the methods `replace` and `toLowerCase` into one statement, **if possible**.

Here is my code:

```
function spinalCase(str) {
  var reg = new RegExp(/([a-zA-Z]+)[^a-zA-Z]/, "g");
  str = str.replace(reg, "$1-");
  var reg2 = new RegExp(/([a-z])([A-Z])/, "g");
  str = str.replace(reg2, "$1-$2");
  str = str.toLowerCase();
  return str;
}
```

`spinalCase("This Is Spinal Tap")` should return `"this-is-spinal-tap"`.
`spinalCase("thisIsSpinalTap")` should return `"this-is-spinal-tap"`.
`spinalCase("The_Andy_Griffith_Show")` should return `"the-andy-griffith-show"`.
`spinalCase("Teletubbies say Eh-oh")` should return `"teletubbies-say-eh-oh"`.
`spinalCase("AllThe-small Things")` should return `"all-the-small-things"`.

Comment: If your code works, it is off-topic at SO. You should consider posting the question at [codereview.se].

Answer (score 2):

You could achieve the same result with below regex (just a matter of piping):

```
([a-z])(?:([A-Z])|[^a-zA-Z])
```

which replaces `$1-$2`:

```js
function spinalCase(s) {
  return s.replace(/([a-z])(?:([A-Z])|[^a-zA-Z\n])/g, '$1-$2').toLowerCase();
}

var str = `This Is Spinal Tap
thisIsSpinalTap
The_Andy_Griffith_Show
Teletubbies say Eh-oh
AllThe-small Things`;

console.log(spinalCase(str));
```